# Rewriting copy constructor with arg shared_ptr

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, shared-ptr

I have a copy constructor for my own dynamic_array, which called TVector.

```
TVector::TVector(TVector &other)
{
    _size = other.length();
    _array = (Square*) malloc(sizeof other);
    for(int i = 0; i < other.length(); ++i){
        _array[i] = other[i];
    }
}
```

and i want to rewrite this constructor using shared_ptr, how can i do this? Tried this, but shared_ptr does not provide subscript operator.

```
TVector::TVector(std::shared_ptr<TVector> other)
{
    _size = other->length();
    std::shared_ptr<Square[]> _array(nullptr);
    for(int i = 0; i < other->length(); ++i){
        _array[i] = other[i];
    }
}
```

```
class TVector {
public:
    TVector();
    TVector(TVector& other);
    virtual ~TVector();
    void Print();
    void push_back(const Square& value);
    void pop_back();
    void clear();
    int length();
    Square& Last();
    Square& operator[](int idx);
    bool empty();
    void resize(int count);
    void erase(size_t pos);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, TVector& s);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, TVector& p);
    int _size;
private:
    Square *_array;
};
```

Comment: `_array = (Square*) malloc(sizeof other);` looks _very_ wrong. Did you really mean to take the (static) size of a `TVector` object as the new size of your backing array? Why not use a basic C++ feature and write `new Square[_size]` instead?

Comment: What you are trying to create is not a copy constructor, it is just a normal constructor that has a shared_ptr as a parameter.

Comment: `TVector::TVector(std::shared_ptr<TVector> p)  { TVector const& other = *p;`

Comment: *"Tried this, but shared_ptr does not provide subscript operator."* -- [it does in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at). Which version of C++ are you using? Which version do you aim to support? *Also, why `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`? The [`unique_ptr` subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at) goes back to C++11.)*